Prove $\sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}} \sqrt{a+b} \ge \sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}} \sqrt{a + bc}$ for $ab + bc + ca + abc =4$

Problem: Given non-negative real numbers $a,b,c$ satisfying $ab+bc+ca+abc=4.$ Prove that
$$\color{blue}{\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{b+c}+\sqrt{c+a}\ge \sqrt{a+bc}+\sqrt{b+ca}+\sqrt{c+ab}.}$$
When does equality hold?

This problem was originally here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h3326949p30914603
Recently, I've found this problem in AoPS forum.
I attempted many times but unsuccesfully. I tried to square both sides, using Holder,... but receive nothing.
Due to its non-homogeneity structure and the square root sign, there're few viable ideas come to my mind. Besides, there are many directions given by the author (in the link) but i think it's not strong enough.
So I want to ask for help or just simply finding some possible ways to approach this problem
Thanh you so much!

I expect we can substitute $a=2\cos\alpha$, $b=2\cos\beta$, and $c=2\cos\gamma$, for some $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in [0,\pi/2]$ with $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\pi$. Unfortunately, I do not see how this helps to prove the required inequality.

Really tedious with Lagrange multipliers but it works.

I think that the method of Lagrange multiplier leads to a horrible system of equations (it is difficult to prove that $a=1, b=1$ is the only one stationary points).

Remark 1. Here is a very complicated solution. We use computer to simplify the expressions.
Remark 2. The equality case is $(a, b, c) = (1, 1, 1)$ and $(a, b, c) = (2, 2, 0)$ and permutations.
We use three bounds for $\sqrt{u}$:
(i) $\sqrt{u} \le \frac{1 + u}{2}$ with equality $u = 1$;
(ii) $\sqrt{u} \ge \frac{2u}{1 + u}$ with equality $u = 1$;
(iii) $\sqrt{u} \le \frac{8u\sqrt{2} + u^2 + 6u + 8}{2u\sqrt{2} + 8\sqrt{2} + 4u + 8}$ with equality $u = 2$ or $u = 4$.
WLOG, assume that $a \ge b \ge c$.
Let
$$A := a + b, \quad B := b + c, \quad C := c + a,$$
$$P := a + bc, \quad Q := b + ca, \quad R := c + ab.$$
We need to prove that
$$\sqrt{A} + \sqrt{B} + \sqrt{C} \ge \sqrt{P} + \sqrt{Q} + \sqrt{R}.$$
We have
$$\sqrt{A} - \sqrt{P} = \frac{A - P}{\sqrt{A} + \sqrt{P}}
\ge \frac{A - P}{\frac{8A\sqrt{2} + A^2 + 6A + 8}{2A\sqrt{2} + 8\sqrt{2} + 4A + 8} + \sqrt{2} \cdot \frac{1 + P/2}{2}},$$
and
$$\sqrt{Q} - \sqrt{B} = \frac{Q - B}{\sqrt{Q} + \sqrt{B}}
\le \frac{Q - B}{\sqrt{2}\cdot \frac{Q}{1 + Q/2} + \sqrt{2} \cdot \frac{B}{1 + B/2}},$$
and
$$\sqrt{C} \ge \sqrt{2}\cdot \frac{C}{1 + C/2},$$
and
$$\sqrt{R} \le \frac{8R\sqrt{2} + R^2 + 6R + 8}{2R\sqrt{2} + 8\sqrt{2} + 4R + 8}.$$
It suffices to prove that
\begin{align*}
 &\frac{A - P}{\frac{8A\sqrt{2} + A^2 + 6A + 8}{2A\sqrt{2} + 8\sqrt{2} + 4A + 8} + \sqrt{2} \cdot \frac{1 + P/2}{2}} - \frac{Q - B}{\sqrt{2}\cdot \frac{Q}{1 + Q/2} + \sqrt{2} \cdot \frac{B}{1 + B/2}}\\[6pt]
 &\qquad + \sqrt{2}\cdot \frac{C}{1 + C/2} - \frac{8R\sqrt{2} + R^2 + 6R + 8}{2R\sqrt{2} + 8\sqrt{2} + 4R + 8}\ge 0. \tag{1}
\end{align*}
Now we deal with the constraint $ab + bc + ca + abc = 4$.
We use the known parameterization:
$$a = \frac{2x}{y + z}, b = \frac{2y}{z + x}, c = \frac{2z}{x + y}.$$
$a \ge b \ge c$ yields $x \ge y \ge z$.
To prove (1), we use the Buffalo Way (BW).
Let $y = z + s, x = z + s + t$ for $s, t \ge 0$.
(1) is equivalently written as
$g(z, s, t)\ge 0$ where $g(z, s, t)$ is a polynomial with non-negative coefficients.
We are done.

This is not an answer since it is not in the spirit of AoPS problems.
As I wrote in an ealier comment, considering
$$\text{lhs} =\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{b+c}+\sqrt{c+a}$$
$$\text{rhs} = \sqrt{a+bc}+\sqrt{b+ca}+\sqrt{c+ab}$$
$$f(a,b,c)=\text{lhs}-\text{rhs}$$ using the fact that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positive plus the given constraint, the method of Lagrange multipliers witj KKT conditions allow to minimize $f(a,b,c)$ even if it is particulary tedious.
Another solution was to extract $c$ from the given constraint
$$c=\frac{4-a b}{a+b+ab}$$ reducing the problem to the minimization of $g(a,b)$.
Around $a=b=1$, expanding $g(a,b)$ as a Taylor series  to second order
$$g(a,b)=\frac{(a-1)^2+(a-1)(b-1)+(b-1)^2}{24 \sqrt{2}}~ >~0$$
Using directional derivatives (as here)
$$g(a,b)=\frac{(a-1)^2+(a-1)(b-1)+(b-1)^2}{24 \sqrt{2}}\,t^2+O(t^3)$$  where $t\to 1$.

1. Restatement of Problem to Reference Its Equations


Problem: Given non-negative real numbers $a,b,c$ satisfying $$ab+bc+ca+abc=4.\tag{Eq. 1.1} $$ Prove that
$$\color{blue}{\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{b+c}+\sqrt{c+a}\ge \sqrt{a+bc}+\sqrt{b+ca}+\sqrt{c+ab}.}\tag{Eq. 1.2}$$
When does equality hold?
This problem was originally here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h3326949p30914603


2.  Solution Steps
Equation 1.1 is an equation of 3 variables $a$, $b$, and $c$, so it can be used to reduce Equation 1.2 to an equation of two variables, Equation 2.1 which then can be plotted when $f\left(b,c\right)>0$ in Equation 2.2 to find out when the inequality holds using numerical methods:
$$a=\left(\frac{4-bc}{b+c+bc}\right)\tag{2.1}$$
$$\begin{align}f\left(b,c\right)&=\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{b+c}+\sqrt{c+a}-\left( \sqrt{a+bc}+\sqrt{b+ca}+\sqrt{c+ab}\right)\\
&=\sqrt{\left(\frac{4-bc}{b+c+bc}\right)+b}+\sqrt{b+c}+\sqrt{c+\left(\frac{4-bc}{b+c+bc}\right)} -\\ & \left( \sqrt{\left(\frac{4-bc}{b+c+bc}\right)+bc}+\sqrt{b+c\left(\frac{4-bc}{b+c+bc}\right)}+\sqrt{c+\left(\frac{4-bc}{b+c+bc}\right)b}\right)
\end{align}\tag{2.2}$$
3. Desmos 3-Dimensional Plots for a Solution Using Numerical Techniques
Three dimensional plots can now be made using the Desmos 3-D calculator, with $b\to x$, $c \to y$ and $f \to z$ as follows:
First of all the regions $b>0$ correspond to $x>0$, the regions $c>0$ correspond to the region $y>0$;  and the region $a>0$ corresponds (From Equation 2.1) to $4-b\,c>0$.  The plot settings for $x$ and $y$ were set equivalently. These are the regions where the Equality Equation 1.2 holds, given of course that $a\ge 0$, $b\ge 0$ and $c \ge 0$ has conditions of the question.
The Desmos 3-D Calculator Equations are quoted thus, with the top Equation being that for the variable $a$ and the bottom Equation being that Equivalent to Equation 2.2:



The Desmos plot itself (with the boundaries for plotting according to the regions defined in the question as earlier discussed) is quoted as:



No additional bounds besides $a\ge 0$, $b\ge 0$, $c\ge 0$ and $4-b\,c \ge 0$ are required for $f\left(b,c\right)>0$ and thus for Equation 1.2 in the question to hold.  The inequality $4-b\,c\ge 0$ of course can be rewritten as $4 \ge b\,c$ so  $\frac{4}{b}\ge c$ or $\frac{4}{c}\ge b$ with direct algebraic simplification.
